# Correct terminology to properly search

Tags: c++

I have some programming experience (mid-2nd year of 4 year program, and some personal experience) writing  programs in Java, C, Javascript, PHP, etc... And now I want to learn more on my own about writing executables that pass information between eachother and remain "idle", but active in the meantime. This has not been covered yet, but I'll need it for a personal project.

Can anyone tell me what that concept is called, and perhaps where to begin, so I can start learning about it?

Comment: Interprocess communication?

Comment: This depends on how your "modules" are used. Should they be used on the same system, at the same time? Should they be used over a network?

Comment: Should be used in the same system, same time. The system is a server.

Answer (score 1):

Read tutorial's on Multithreading c/c++ program development , also for passing msg's b/w different process you can use Socket API or Inter Process Communication (IPC) . You can refer book http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/productCd-0470147628.html which include all these stuffs ( Specific to linux , for cross platform u can use QT http://qt.nokia.com/ )

Comment: Oh ok. So communicating between them is kind of like networking then with sockets. Thanks for the info.

Comment: u can also use sharedQues in linux , just go through the book http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/productCd-0470147628.html in detail

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to communicate between processes. For Windows there is always the WCF in .NET

The most useful and easy way I find is using sockets for IPC, it works both Unix and Windows platforms.
The next best thing is a local DB, like SQLite.

I did not understand the second part of your question.

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/unix_sockets/index.htm

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735119(v=vs.90).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Who are "each other"? Depending on this, you might want to learn client-server or peer-to-peer architecture concepts. You will need to get knowledge of network communication and multithreading.